# Запись результатов выполнения скрипта в python

Tags: python

Здраствуйте!
У меня проблема с записью результатов работы скрипта в файл. В этом фрагменте кода:

```
print 'ip: ', sw.ip_sw.ljust(15), '\tlocation: ', name_adr.split(' ')[-2].rjust(20), '\tports UP: ', str(sw.ports_up).rjust(2), '\tports DOWN: ', str(sw.ports_down).rjust(2), '\tports ALL: ', str(sw.ports_up+sw.ports_down).rjust(3)
```

Я вывожу результаты значения на экран. Тоже самое нужно, чтобы записывалось в файл.Конструкция такого типа:

```
fil = open('./portlog', 'w')
fil.write(sw.ip_sw, name_adr, sw.ports_up, sw.ports_down, sw.ports_up+sw.ports_down)
fil.close()
```

Не работает. Подскажите, что я неправильно делаю.

Comment: см. ответ или наберите print fil.write.__doc__

Comment: И ещё, в python3 print уже другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите получить в своём portlog, но возможно Вам подойдёт

```
fil = open('./portlog', 'w')
print >>fil, 'ip: ', sw.ip_sw.ljust(15), 'tlocation: ', name_adr.split(' ')[-2].rjust(20), 'tports UP: ', str(sw.ports_up).rjust(2), 'tports DOWN: ', str(sw.ports_down).rjust(2), 'tports ALL: ', str(sw.ports_up+sw.ports_down).rjust(3
```

А в Вашем варианте методу `write` (с одним параметром) Вы пытаетесь передать несколько

Comment: Огромное спасибо!) то что нужно.. исправил и все заработало...

Answer (score 1):

```
fil.write(sw.ip_sw, name_adr, sw.ports_up, sw.ports_down, sw.ports_up+sw.ports_down)
```

Синтаксис нарушен. У `write` один параметр.